# SQLAlchemy switch to python multiprocessing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing, mariadb, web-crawler

I am currently working on a web crawler. It works fine but I want to maximise the ressources I am trying to switch to multi-processing. But the second I try that I run into a wall of tracebacks and I cant seam to find what I am doing wrong as I am still novice with both SQLAlchemy and Python multi-processing.

Here is how the parent loop looks like:

```
...
def crawler(url=False):
    ...
    while url:
        crawl(url.id)
        url = get_new_url()
```

I am trying to turn this into a parallel processing function where I dont have to wait for the previous crawl/scrape to be finished:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
...
def crawler(url=False):
    while url:
        p = Process(target=crawl, args=(url.id,))
        p.start()
        url = get_new_url()
```

Here is how I make my database connection:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@domain:3306/mdb01?charset=utf8mb4', pool_recycle=3600)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Here is the modules doing the crawling's database interactions and the importing of the database factory (I removed the bulk as I feel the issue is how I interact with sqlalchemy and not the rest of the code):

```
from news_models.base import Base, Session, engine
database = Session()

def crawl(urlid):
    url = database.query(Url).filter_by(id=urlid).first()

    print(f"Starting to work on {url.id}: {url.url}")

    ... scrape page ....
    scrape = scrape_url(url)

    ... running beautifull soup ...

    # Retrieve all of the anchor tags
    tags = soup('a')

    for tag in tags:
        ... validation ...
        make_url(url)

 def make_url(url):
    ...
    #domain = ex. abc.com
    domain = database.query(Domain).filter_by(domain=domain).first()
    database.add(Url(url, domain, vetted))
    database.commit()

 def scrape_url(url):
    scrape = Scrape(page = html, url = url)
    database.add(scrape)
    database.commit()
    return scrape
```

Here is the dialog:

```
Starting to work on 179226: https://bbc.co.uk/sport/football/53891604
Starting to work on 110232: https://theweathernetwork.com/ca/weather/saskatchewan/carragana
Starting to work on 152054: https://ca.images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?p=barack+obama&fr=fp-tts&th=110.1&tw=162.6&imgurl=https%3a%2f%2fimage.cnbcfm.com%2fapi%2fv1%2fimage%2f105055178-gettyimages-680143744rr.jpg%3fv%3d1576513702%26w%3d1400%26h%3d950&rurl=https%3a%2f%2fwww.cnbc.com%2f2019%2f12%2f16%2fbarack-obama-how-women-are-better-leaders-than-men.html&size=123kb&name=barack+obama%3a+how+women+are+better+leaders+than+men&oid=1&h=950&w=1400&turl=https%3a%2f%2ftse1.mm.bing.net%2fth%3fid%3doip.btjoweh9kdcuxxcdksvoiwhafb%26amp%3bpid%3dapi%26rs%3d1%26c%3d1%26qlt%3d95%26w%3d162%26h%3d110&tt=barack+obama%3a+how+women+are+better+leaders+than+men&sigr=4nejz_6_wyyo&sigit=.iypm9cqprc9&sigi=9sv3ee5szhdl&sign=eqzxpc3ps9fm&sigt=eqzxpc3ps9fm
Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 321, in scrape_url
    database.add(scrape)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2008, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2021, in _save_or_update_state
    self._save_or_update_impl(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2371, in _save_or_update_impl
    self._save_impl(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2324, in _save_impl
    to_attach = self._before_attach(state, obj)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2441, in _before_attach
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Scrape at 0x7f4f7e1975b0>' is already attached to session '3' (this is '2')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 697, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 893, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2475, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
Process Process-3:
Process Process-1:
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./crawler.py", line 138, in <module>
    main()
  File "./crawler.py", line 49, in main
    crawler(url=url)
  File "./crawler.py", line 135, in crawler
    url = get_new_url()
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 482, in get_new_url
    url = database.query(Url).filter_by(scrape=None, error=False).order_by(sqlalchemy.func.rand()).first()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3402, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3176, in __getitem__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 321, in scrape_url
    database.add(scrape)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2008, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2021, in _save_or_update_state
    self._save_or_update_impl(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2371, in _save_or_update_impl
    self._save_impl(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2324, in _save_impl
    to_attach = self._before_attach(state, obj)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2441, in _before_attach
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Scrape at 0x7f4f7e1e3790>' is already attached to session '3' (this is '2')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 749, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2475, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
    return list(res)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3508, in __iter__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 62, in crawl
    soup = scrape_and_soup(url)
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 331, in scrape_and_soup
    scrape = scrape_url(url)
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 325, in scrape_url
    database.rollback()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1006, in rollback
    self.transaction.rollback()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 574, in rollback
    util.raise_(rollback_err[1], with_traceback=rollback_err[2])
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 534, in rollback
    t[1].rollback()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1753, in rollback
    self._do_rollback()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1791, in _do_rollback
    self.connection._rollback_impl()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 751, in _rollback_impl
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, None, None, None, None)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 749, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2475, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 321, in scrape_url
    database.add(scrape)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2008, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2021, in _save_or_update_state
    self._save_or_update_impl(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2371, in _save_or_update_impl
    self._save_impl(state)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2324, in _save_impl
    to_attach = self._before_attach(state, obj)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2441, in _before_attach
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Scrape at 0x7f4f7e1e3a60>' is already attached to session '3' (this is '2')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 749, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2475, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 62, in crawl
    soup = scrape_and_soup(url)
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 331, in scrape_and_soup
    scrape = scrape_url(url)
  File "/home/fabrice/workbench/news/news_crawler/crawl_tools.py", line 325, in scrape_url
    database.rollback()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1006, in rollback
    self.transaction.rollback()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 574, in rollback
    util.raise_(rollback_err[1], with_traceback=rollback_err[2])
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 534, in rollback
    t[1].rollback()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1753, in rollback
    self._do_rollback()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1791, in _do_rollback
    self.connection._rollback_impl()
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 751, in _rollback_impl
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, None, None, None, None)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 749, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2475, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3533, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/fabrice/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
[SQL: SELECT urls.id AS urls_id, urls.url AS urls_url, urls.error AS urls_error, urls.vetted AS urls_vetted, urls.useful AS urls_useful, urls.date_discovered AS urls_date_discovered, urls.last_parse AS urls_last_parse, urls.domain_id AS urls_domain_id, urls.publisher_id AS urls_publisher_id 
FROM urls 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM scrapes 
WHERE urls.id = scrapes.url_id)) AND urls.error = false ORDER BY rand() 
 LIMIT %s]
[parameters: (1,)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

I've tryed playing with create_engine adding pool_size=20, max_overflow=0 or autoflush=True/False to no success.

Could someone please indicate what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to make a new database session in each process, at the start of the `crawl` function (then pass it into `make_url` and `scrape_url`, either as a separate parameter or by making them all methods of one object). You should use a `with closing(...)` statement to make sure the session is closed when `crawl` finishes.

You have another problem in the code: the `while url` loop needs to also wait for all the scrapers to finish, in case one of them finds additional URLs that also need to be scraped.

As a suggestion for improvement, rather than using `Process` directly, you could use `multiprocessing.Pool`; that would let you control the number of scrapers running in parallel, which you'll probably eventually want to do (to avoid overloading the CPU, RAM, network and/or database). At that point, you could either still use a separate database session for each `crawl` call, or one per pool worker.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the global database session and instead let the parent create one that is passed to the called functions and it now worked. Not the performance increase I had in mind. As per the pool to limit processes. Process without arguments will limit itself to a pool, of the number of cores. Since I run my apps in self-contained lxc's I can controll that from the outside giving it more or less virtual cores.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Process` will not limit itself; it'll spawn as many as you ask. The CPU cores will limit the amount of local processing, but you can still run out of RAM or overload the network, the websites you're scraping, or the database. Controlling that via the cores is going to be difficult to impossible, since both network and database connections involve very little local processing. It'll happily run up hundreds or thousands of processes, each of which fires off a database connection request then sits there waiting for the poor database to deal with the flood.

Comment: As for performance increase - one way would be to put the queue of URLs to be scraped somewhere other than the database; even just passing the details of the URL into `crawl` rather than just the `id` would save one database round-trip, but putting it into a different queueing system would be even faster. A process pool would let you have a database session per worker, saving the session set-up costs (as well as process start-up costs). Then there's small (but probably expensive) details like moving the `domain` query and the `commit` in `make_url` out of the `for tag in tags` loop.

Comment: I simplified greatly here to target my issue (from =- 1000 lines) so it is not fully representative of the real implementation. I passed the id to crawl to keep the database session separate between the parent and crawl and its children which runs in a separate process.

Comment: Simplified — fair enough. Counting database round-trips is probably a useful approach, though; they're often nearly invisible yet quite expensive. For passing the URL, the trick would be to construct the `Scrape` object with just the `id` of the URL, not the full `Url` object.